# How to sort CakePHP multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

Find statements in CakePHP produce an array structured as below. **I've already ordered my search** to produce the result set shown (ordered by combined_score).  Now, I'd like to apply a sorting function on the data to sort by "average_votes".  See "from this:"/"to this:" below.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

```
From this:
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Vehicle] => Array
            (
                [id] => 52
                [user_id] => 101
                [name] => Ford
                [total_votes] => 5
                [average_votes] => 3.8
                [combined_score] => 19
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Vehicle] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48
                [user_id] => 101
                [name] => Nissan
                [total_votes] => 6
                [average_votes] => 5
                [combined_score] => 2
            )
    )
)

To this:
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Vehicle] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48
                [user_id] => 101
                [name] => Nissan
                [total_votes] => 6
                [average_votes] => 5
                [combined_score] => 2
            )
    )   

[1] => Array
    (
        [Vehicle] => Array
            (
                [id] => 52
                [user_id] => 101
                [name] => Ford
                [total_votes] => 5
                [average_votes] => 3.8
                [combined_score] => 19
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Please look at the "Related" section on the right.

Comment: Why don't you have the database do the sorting?

Comment: Jon, which of these related links show how to sort by data 3 levels deep as shown above?

Comment: Ori, I have asked the database to sort by combined_score, and then with that result set, I need to sort by average_votes. Do you have any suggestions on how to do what you say?

Comment: Now you should have enough rep to self-answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you're actually trying to achieve you can still do this at the database level in cake, like so:

```
$this->Vehicle->find('all',array('order' => array('Vehicle.combined_score' => 'asc', 'Vehicle.average_votes' => 'desc')));
```

Which will first sort by combined score, and then sort by average votes

The second option is to use the cakephp Set class, like so:

```
$results = Set::sort($results, '{n}.Vehicle.average_votes', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 2):

In your controller the find function you can add option for sorting.

```
$this->Vehicle->find('all',array('order' => array('Vehicle.average_votes DESC')));
```

Comment: Thanks gvLearner, but as I mentioned in my post, I need it first sorted by combined_score, and then I need to take that result set and resort it by average votes.